# Is it possible to use Boost Program Options without RTTI?

Tags: c++, rtti, boost-program-options, boost-any

I would like to disable RTTI in a project of mine. However, this project uses Boost Program Options which itself depends on Boost Any which does not support -fno-rtti.

I was wondering if there was any solution to use Boost Program without RTTI ? By defining a macro or by not using some of the features ?

Thanks

Comment: program options use boost::any anyway, since there is no abilities to use boost::any without RTTI, you cannot use boost::po without RTTI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "no". Boost.PO is based on Boost.Any and this dependence can't be avoided by users currently. Boost.Any gives the main storage structure of Boost.PO so you can't compile some useful part of PO without Any.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "maybe". Some boost libraries will work with exceptions disabled - some will not. Same for RTTI.

I suggest you check the documentation for the particular boost libraries that you are interested in.

For example, Boost.Array will work with exceptions disabled, but Boost.Format will not.

If you are getting messages like cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti, that will probably be while compiling some part of Boost that requires RTTI. Where the error occurs will tell you which library (usually).

You can try BOOST_NO_RTTI and BOOST_NO_TYPEID ...

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/exception/doc/configuration_macros.html

Comment: I tried the two macros you suggested, unfortunately it does not make any difference for boost Any. But it indeed work for other libraries like Boost Variant.